# Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm looping my object data but am getting this undefined value.

Not sure why but was hoping some one can explain.

My object is like this:

```
//globally set
var sdata = {"4":{"7":["1","7","3","3"]},"3":{"3":["2","8","1","1"]}};
```

And i loop the object like this:

```
function is_occupied(position) {
    for (var x in sdata) {
        for (var y in sdata) {
            // error's here Cannot read property '2' of undefined
            var ex = sdata[x][y][2] > position.block_width ? (sdata[x][y][2] + (sdata[x][y][2] - position.block_width)) : sdata[x][y][2],
            var ey = sdata[x][y][3] > position.block_height ? (sdata[x][y][3] + (sdata[x][y][3] - position.block_height)) : sdata[x][y][3];
            if (position.x >= sdata[x][y][2] && position.x <= ex && position.y >= sdata[x][y][3] && position.y <= ey) {
                alert('hit');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why it would say its undefined ? =/ Can't work it out. Its suppose to be getting position [2] in the array data of that object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to be looping over `sdata[x]`, not `sdata` in your inner loop:

```
function is_occupied(position) {
    for(var x in sdata){
     for(var y in sdata[x]){
```

Comment: Ah ! Good spot Sir!! So it was! :)